# Is it possible to use php sessions with any internet provider?

Tags: php, session-variables, session-cookies

I'm creating a web application with php and this web application works perfectly in my home but when I tried to use in a company with two of the networks did not work, I mean I can access to the site but there are a lot of sessions lost,destroyed even if I dont refresh or navigate, specially when everybody are using internet, also sometimes when I enter to the page this redirect me to a similiar domain with this in the begining: `ww7`

This is my code:

```
    <?php
//Genera un password para el empleado o el cliente
function generaPass(){
    //Se define una cadena de caractares. Te recomiendo que uses esta.
    $cadena = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    //Obtenemos la longitud de la cadena de caracteres
    $longitudCadena=strlen($cadena);

    //Se define la variable que va a contener la contraseña
    $pass = "";
    //Se define la longitud de la contraseña, en mi caso 10, pero puedes poner la longitud que quieras
    $longitudPass=10;

    //Creamos la contraseña
    for($i=1 ; $i<=$longitudPass ; $i++){
        //Definimos numero aleatorio entre 0 y la longitud de la cadena de caracteres-1
        $pos=rand(0,$longitudCadena-1);

        //Vamos formando la contraseña en cada iteraccion del bucle, añadiendo a la cadena $pass la letra correspondiente a la posicion $pos en la cadena de caracteres definida.
        $pass .= substr($cadena,$pos,1);
    }
    return $pass;
}



/**
 * @param $required_fields_array, n array containing the list of all required fields
 * @return array, containing all errors
 */
function check_empty_fields($required_fields_array){
    //initialize an array to store error messages
    $form_errors = array();
    //loop through the required fields array snd popular the form error array
    foreach($required_fields_array as $name_of_field){
        if(!isset($_POST[$name_of_field]) || $_POST[$name_of_field] == NULL){
            $form_errors[] = $name_of_field . " is a required field";
        }
    }
    return $form_errors;
}

/**
 * @param $fields_to_check_length, an array containing the name of fields
 * for which we want to check min required length e.g array('username' => 4, 'email' => 12)
 * @return array, containing all errors
 */
function check_min_length($fields_to_check_length){
    //initialize an array to store error messages
    $form_errors = array();
    foreach($fields_to_check_length as $name_of_field => $minimum_length_required){
        if(strlen(trim($_POST[$name_of_field])) < $minimum_length_required && $_POST[$name_of_field] != NULL){
            $form_errors[] = $name_of_field . " is too short, must be {$minimum_length_required} characters long";
        }
    }
    return $form_errors;
}

/**
 * @param $data, store a key/value pair array where key is the name of the form control
 * in this case 'email' and value is the input entered by the user
 * @return array, containing email error
 */
function check_email($data){
    //initialize an array to store error messages
    $form_errors = array();
    $key = 'email';
    //check if the key email exist in data array
    if(array_key_exists($key, $data)){

        //check if the email field has a value
        if($_POST[$key] != null){

            // Remove all illegal characters from email
            filter_var($_POST[$key], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

            //check if input is a valid email address
            if(filter_var($_POST[$key], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
                $form_errors[] = $key . " is not a valid email address";
            }
        }
    }
    return $form_errors;
}

/**
 * @param $form_errors_array, the array holding all
 * errors which we want to loop through
 * @return string, list containing all error messages
 */
function show_errors($form_errors_array){
    $errors = "<p><ul style='color: red;'>";

    //loop through error array and display all items in a list
    foreach($form_errors_array as $the_error){
        $errors .= "<li> {$the_error} </li>";
    }
    $errors .= "</ul></p>";
    return $errors;
}

/**
 * @param $message, message to display
 * @param string $passOrFail, test condition to determine message type
 * @return string, returns the message
 */
function flashMessage($message, $passOrFail = "Fail"){
    if($passOrFail === "Pass"){
        $data = "<div class='alert alert-success'>{$message}</p>";
    }else{
        $data = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>{$message}</p>";
    }

    return $data;
}

/**
 * @param $page, redirect user to page specified
 */
function redirectTo($page){
    header("Location: {$page}.php");
}

/**
 * @param $table, table that we want to search
 * @param $column_name, the column name
 * @param $value, the data collected from the form
 * @param $db, database object
 * @return bool, returns true if record exist else false
 */
function checkDuplicateEntries($table, $column_name, $value, $db){
    try{
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $column_name=:$column_name";
        $statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);  
        $statement->execute(array(":$column_name" => $value));

        if($row = $statement->fetch()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }catch (PDOException $ex){
        //handle exception
    }
}



function signout(){
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    unset($_SESSION['id']);
    unset($_SESSION['coa']);
        unset($_SESSION['registrar_usuarios']);
unset($_SESSION['capturar_pedidos']);
unset($_SESSION['salida_materiales']);
unset($_SESSION['alta_clientes']);
unset($_SESSION['alta_productos']);
unset($_SESSION['usuario_cliente']);
unset($_SESSION['cliente']);

    session_destroy();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    redirectTo('index');
}

/**
 *
 * @return bool, true if all good
 */
function guard(){

    $isValid = true;
    $fingerprint = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

    if((isset($_SESSION['fingerprint']) && $_SESSION['fingerprint'] != $fingerprint)){
        $isValid = false;
        signout();
    }

    return $isValid;
}

function isValidImage($file){
    $form_errors = array();

    //split file name into an array using the dot (.)
    $part = explode(".", $file);

    //target the last element in the array
    $extension = end($part);

    switch(strtolower($extension)){
        case 'jpg':
        case 'gif':
        case 'bmp':
        case 'png':

        return $form_errors;
    }

    $form_errors[] = $extension . " is not a valid image extension";
    return $form_errors;
}

function uploadAvatar($username){
    if($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']){

        //File in the temp location
        $temp_file = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['avatar']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $filename = $username.md5(microtime()).".{$ext}";

        $path = __DIR__ . "/../../../../uploadscsrnacional/{$filename}"; //uploads/demo.jpg
        move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $path);

        return $path;
    }

    return false;
}

function _token(){
    $randonToken = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
    //$randonToken = md5(uniqid(rand(), true))." md5";

    return $_SESSION['token'] = $randonToken;
}

function validate_token($requestToken){
    if(isset($_SESSION['token']) && $requestToken === $_SESSION['token']){
        unset($_SESSION['token']);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function prepLogin ($id, $username, $coa,$registrar_usuarios, $capturar_pedidos,$salida_materiales,$alta_clientes,$alta_productos, $usuario_cliente, $cliente){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['coa'] = $coa;
    $_SESSION['registrar_usuarios'] = $registrar_usuarios;
     $_SESSION['capturar_pedidos'] = $capturar_pedidos;
      $_SESSION['salida_materiales'] = $salida_materiales;
     $_SESSION['alta_clientes'] = $alta_clientes;
     $_SESSION['alta_productos'] = $alta_productos;
     $_SESSION['usuario_cliente'] = $usuario_cliente;
     $_SESSION['cliente'] = $cliente;

    $fingerprint = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $_SESSION['fingerprint'] = $fingerprint;


    echo $welcome = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            swal({
                            title: \"Welcome back $username! \",
                            text: \"You're being logged in.\",
                            type: 'success',
                            timer: 3000,
                            showConfirmButton: false });
                            setTimeout(function(){
                               window.location.href = 'index.php';
                            }, 3000);
                        </script>";
}
```

and this the .htaccess above the subfolder because my whole project is in this subfolder so my project is inside another old project, I dont know who created this site

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: How you make that upside down question mark, that's what I want to know?  Oh, it went away ... :-(

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake and I wrote an sign from my language it is just another symbol

Comment: I wouldn't say it was a mistake, it was Awesome, wish I had some those inverted `?`  see no entity codes &‌iquest;

Comment: Ok on to the fun stuff, do you have error reporting turned on, cookies can be sensitive to output, headers being sent.

Comment: First thing I would do is take that line you are destroying the cookie on, and comment that sucker out,  `setcookie('rememberUserCookie', null, -1, '/');`  Your cookies may be fine, but you might be getting logged out and destroying it.

Comment: Worse yet this is very insecure,  I think I could spoof your remember me cookie pretty easily, and gain access to any account that I wanted.

Comment: FIrs of all, I just called signout(); when someone click on logout.php link  and secondly I followed a tutorial in order to create this login and I focused on the crud and other things that my system can do. Do you know about a php login that works on any host cpanel? because the owner from this company doesnt want to pay for another host, I even added permissions to the system and it works with almost every network but I know that is insecure

Comment: This code is crap, sorry to tell you that, but I could hack it in like 15 minutes and log in as any user on the system.

Comment: That is not true, `signout();` is also called if the cookie is set but the userID is not found in the database.  This could happen if there was some error in pulling the ID from the cookie data.

Comment: Hey I decided to delete remember cookie now I just keep token and sessions is now secure? I edited my code here

Answer (score 1):

The main issue I see here, unless I am missing something is that it may be possible to create a cookie for you domain, or modify a cookie for your domain and login as a different user.

I took this function and removed all your comments, and added some of my own.  First we will work on solving your issue with this not working.  Then we should address the vulnerability of the methodology used for this.

```
<?php
//add these at the top of you script - to make sure we can see the errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting(-1);

function isCookieValid(PDO $db){
    //Debug the $db variable - is this a valid PDO connetion. Added type hinting.

    echo "<pre>"; //for debugging formatting

    $isValid = false;
    if (isset($_COOKIE['rememberUserCookie'])) {

        // This is vaunerable to spoofing
        $decryptCookieData = base64_decode($_COOKIE['rememberUserCookie']);

        //check the cookie value
        var_dum($decryptCookieData);

        $user_id = explode("UaQteh5i4y3dntstemYODEC", $decryptCookieData);
        $userID = $user_id[1];

        //check the userID after parsing it from the cookie
        var_dum($userID);

        //$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id";

        $sqlQuery = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = :id"; //technically we only need the username
        $statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $statement->execute(array(':id' => $userID));

        //Varify that the user exists in the DB

        if(false !== ( $username = $statement->fetchColumn(0))){  //fetch column instead
           /* 
             - A lot of unnessacry assginements here.
             $id = $row['id'];
            $username = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
          */

            $_SESSION['id'] = $userID; //we already know this value, if we didn't we wouldnt be here
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

            $isValid = true;
        }else{

            //Debug for cookie failures
            var_dump("Cookie user {$userID} not found" );

            $isValid = false;
            signout(); //<--- signout is called here, obviously
            /*
                so if this IF condition fails for some reason, the 
                cookie is deleted, this could include DB errors
                etc. depending on your error reporting level, this 
                may not be obvious
            */
        }
    }else{
        var_dump("No Cookie found" );
    }
    return $isValid;
}
```

Hopefully some of these debugging output will shed some light on what is going on.

Now how is this vulnerable.  This code uses `base64` which is not encrypting, its encoding and provides no security benefits.  So lets analyze what I mean by vulnerable, focus on this code:

```
$decryptCookieData = base64_decode($_COOKIE['rememberUserCookie']);
$user_id = explode("UaQteh5i4y3dntstemYODEC", $decryptCookieData);
$userID = $user_id[1];

$sqlQuery = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = :id"; 
$statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
$statement->execute(array(':id' => $userID));

if(false !== ( $username = $statement->fetchColumn(0))){

    $_SESSION['id'] = $userID; 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    $isValid = true;
}else{
   ...  
}
```

So what we are doing here:

- taking the value of the cookie, and parsing a user ID out of it
- then we take that ID and simply check if the user exists in the DB
- then we setup our session to say that I am that user/

Now consider if I had say a basic account on your system, maybe you have a free membership and a paid for membership.  I can take my "remember me" cookie from that free account, and edit its value.  This would let me put any userID in there I want to. This is as simple as changing my cookie to a value like this:

```
VWFRdGVoNWk0eTNkbnRzdGVtWU9ERUM2NjY=
```

Which when it's processed by this script would attempt to log me in as user `666`.  I could try as many integer ID values as I needed to until I got one to work.

Now one could argue, that I have an advantage because I can see the source code. However, it would take very little imagination to look at the cookie and see the ending `=`. Which to me is a pretty clear indication that its base64 encoded.  It's not at all uncommon to encode cookie data that way. Then I would simply decode it. Then I would see something like this:

```
`UaQteh5i4y3dntstemYODEC{myID}`
```

Usually, little or no effort is take to hid the account ID from the account holder.  So seeing that number at the end of this and the fact it never changes would kind of clue me in on what it was.  I've seen people figure out way harder things with way less information than that, so it's entirely possible and likely someone would figure it out.

Now, thankfully there are several easy things we can do to fix this.

The most obvious is to use real encryption on the cookie value.  This would be something like AES256, maybe even OpenSSL.  This is ok, and probably the easiest thing to do.  However, we really don't want to give any important data to the client if we can avoid it.  Certainly we don't want to store account information on the clients system ( the user ID being account information ).

A better option is to break that bond between the users account and the cookie data.  This can be done by having a table to store data in for this feature.  Then when the remember me is set, we create a new record for the user in that table.  This abstracts the users ID, and requires that record be set before their account can be accessed.

When I build these I usually combine them with a "forgotten password" feature. I like to all it a "passport" pun intended.  The only difference with the remember me, is that it's done using a link sent in the email instead of a cookie.  Oh and typically password resets are one time.  But, you could literally setup a record for both in the same table and send the lookup hash in an email for the reset, and save it in a cookie for the remember me.

- We can build this were we use a hashed value that is just some random garbage ( it doesn't matter what it is, that's a good thing) that we use to look up this record.  This makes it hard to guess what value we need for the cookie.

This is much better, but security through obscurity is no real security. So we can still do better.

- We can set a time limit on this record, say its good for 1 month, refreshed when they visit the site.  If it's used after the expiration then we force login.
- We can track the users IP, and only use the record if the IP it was created with matches the current one ( we would want to notify the user that auto login only works on the same IP or such so they don't think it is broken )
- We can delete this record any time we want, we cant delete a users ID, this is why we need to keep that data separate.  ie. we can easily disable this feature.
- We can send an email confirmation to the users email, saying they were logged in using an automated feature.  This would notify them is someone accessed their account without their knowledge.
- We could store the user-agent used when the cookie was created, this shouldn't really change.  If they made the cookie in Edge, they have no business using it in firefox, for example.
- We could ask challenge questions, but I really hate those, and it sort of defeats the purpose.
- We could and should track how and when an account is logged in with.  This depends somewhat on your application.

I am sure there are other things we can do to trip up a hacker. Anything that restricts the use of it, while still being transparent to the user, security should not be based on just one thing.

As I said I can help you refactor this so it's secure.  First we should sort out the cookie issue though.  Once that is sorted out, you can't ignore the security implications of what I pointed out.  This is just to big of a hole to leave un-plugged.

cheers.

**UPDATE**
I mentioned it in the comments so I thought I would give you an example on how to use MySql to get the Databases Schema for validation of column and table names etc.  ( I adapted this from some code I have, so I did't really test it, but it should be close )

```
$statement = 'SELECT `TABLE_NAME`, `ENGINE`, `TABLE_SCHEMA` FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` LIKE :database';
$stmt = $DB->prepare($statement);
$stmt->execute([':database' => $database]);

$shcema = [];
while($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $shcema[$row['TABLE_NAME']] = ['_TABLE_NAME_'=>$row['TABLE_NAME'], '_ENGINE_'=>$row['ENGINE'],'_COLUMNS_' => []];

    $statement = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM `'.$row['TABLE_SCHEMA'].'`.`'.$row['TABLE_NAME'].'`';
    $s = $DB->query($statement);
    while($r = $s->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $shcema[$row['TABLE_NAME']]['_COLUMNS_'][$r['Field']] = $r;
    }
}
```

This should generate something like this

```
$shcema = [ 'someTable' => [
  '_TABLE_NAME_' => 'someTable',
  '_ENGINE_' => 'InnoDB',
  '_COLUMNS_' => [ 
      'id' =>[
          'Field' => 'id',
          'Type' => 'int(10) unsigned',
          'Null' => 'NO',
          'Key' => 'PRI',
          'Default' => NULL,
          'Extra' => 'auto_increment',
        ],[
      'create_date' =>[
          'Field' => 'create_date',
          'Type' => 'date',
          'Null' => 'YES',
          'Key' => '',
          'Default' => NULL,
          'Extra' => '',
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],[ 'someother_table' => [..]
];
```

This is probably more then you need, but basically you just give it a database name and it will find all the tables and build out an array for their schema.  It's pretty cool as you can do some neat stuff with this.

Comment: Well your explanation is awesome for future projects, but due to time I decided to delete remember cookies, I changed my code is now secure without  remember cookies?, I realized that session use a cookie too but should be secure by default, I use sessions values for access list

Comment: Yes, I won't say it's "Secure" as I haven't reviewed it all, but by getting rid of that feature, it will certainly take care of that issue.  Time constraints are understandable and it's better to scale it back then to use bad code.  When I get a minute I will take a look at the other bits, to see if anything else jumps out at me.

Comment: I understand you need see the whole project, by the way do you know what do I need to keep session cookie with bad connections? I put this stuff in my code: <?php
$session_lifetime = 3600 * 24 * 2; // 2 days
session_set_cookie_params ($session_lifetime);
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","7200"); 

session_start();

Comment: Sorry, only thing I can think to try for the session is either change where it's saving them ( I had a sever one time that the session folder was shared for multiple sites, and it would overwrite my files ) or save them to the DB with `session_set_save_handler()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php  I usually write my own session handler.

Comment: AS far as the rest of the code it doesn't look to bad, one thing to watch out for is this query `$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $column_name=:$column_name";`  (as I don't know here the input is set ) This might be fine, but just never concatenation user supplied variables into your SQL.  You could use the DB to check that  `$column_name` exists in `$table`, not sure the query right off, but the `SHOW ...` family of SQL is useful for schema checks.

Comment: That said, that query may be fine as long as the variables cant be set by a end user.  Generally though it's better to validate that data against the Database schema inside that function, that way you don't accidentally put something that could be set by a user.  FYI, this could lead to a SQL Injection vulnerability.